# Android で動画の２倍速再生 or スロー再生を実装するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

動画機能を実装したいので、「再生・停止・ポーズ・早送り・巻き戻し」の機能は実装しました。

しかし倍速・スロー再生を実装する方法がわからず調査しまくっています。

Android の `MediaPlayer` クラスには速度を変えるメソッドがなく、どのように実装したら良いかわからない状態です。

知見をお持ちの方いらしたら教えてください。

Comment: 質問文と無関係な 'unity3d' タグを取り除きました。

Answer (score 4):

[`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) (もしくは `ViewoView`) を使って、再生速度を変更することはできません。

ご存じのように、数ある動画再生プレイヤーアプリの中には、再生速度の調整ができるものがあります。昔、それらのソフトウェアが依存しているライブラリのチェックをしたことがありますが、大体のソフトウェアがバックエンドで [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) を使用していました。 Stack Overflow の類似の質問では、標準以外のプレイヤーコンポーネントも紹介されていますが、同じく ffmpeg 依存です。公開されているものは不便もあるようですので、細かな要求がある場合は、 ffmpeg を利用しつつ、ご自分で動画再生の表示部を作られることになるでしょう。

**参考**:

- Stack Overflow, [Android Video Playback Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270445/android-video-playback-speed)
- Stack Overflow, [Using FFmpeg with Android-NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605757/using-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk)
- ffmpeg, [wiki:CompilationGuide/Android](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android)
- プレイヤ部品: [Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle) / [Presto](http://www.aocate.com/presto/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、
情報が全く得られず困っておりました。 おっしゃる通りで世の中にはスロー再生や倍速再生できるアプリが多々あるのに
何故できないのか？と疑問に思っておりました。
ffmpegについては名前すらも知りませんでした。 まずは現場に今後ffmpegの解析をして実装する方向にするかを確認します。 下記、２点を知ることができましただけでも、大きな収穫です。 ・AndroidのMediaPlayer(VideoView)クラスでは実装できない。
・ffmpegを解析し、機能を実装することは可能。

Answer (score 1):

`MediaPlayer`相当の機能をユーザアプリケーションとして実装した、[ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html)がGoogleより提供されています。こちらの実装をベースにして、再生時間の管理部分を弄る方法もあります。

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer