# androidでmp3を2倍速で再生するには

Tags: android

androidでmp3を2倍速で再生しようとしています。

SoundPoolのplayには、
public final int play (int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)
rate：再生速度（0.5〜2.0：0.5倍から2倍の速度まで設定できる）とありました。

今回、再生するmp3は長さが1時間ぐらいのなので、SoundPoolでは再生できそうにないので、別の方法を探しています。すみませんがアドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: すでに[過去に同じ質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6438/android-%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BB%E3%81%AE%EF%BC%92%E5%80%8D%E9%80%9F%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F-or-%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B/6444#6444)があったようです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

自己レスです。
音程を変えずに2倍速で再生することができました。

以下のExoPlayerとsonicを組み合わせることで実現できました。
https://github.com/ariestiyansyah/indonesiax-android-app
https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic-ndk

ExoPlayerでは、MediaCodecでmp3をデコードしてそれをAudioTrackに出力して再生していました。それを、AudioTrackに出力する前に、sonicの音声の波形データを加工する処理を追加することで2倍速で再生できました。

ソースの変更箇所は、ごくわずかで思ってより簡単に済みました。アドバイスありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

`AudioTrack`というクラスで`setPlaybackRate(int sampleRateInHz)`が使えます。
http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setPlaybackRate(int)

ただしこのクラスは音声の波形データを再生するためのクラスなので、
`MediaCodec`や`MediaExtractor`と合わせて使うことになります。
SoundPoolよりも使い勝手は落ちますがご質問の内容と同等のことが可能です。

またAPI Level 23以上であれば、`MediaPlayer`の`setPlaybackParams`を使うことで
音声ファイルの再生速度を変更することが可能です。
http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setPlaybackParams(android.media.PlaybackParams)

ご質問には特に書かれていませんでしたが、こちらの方法では音程を保ったまま再生速度を変更することができます。
（逆に言うとSoundPoolやAudioTrackでは再生速度を変えると音程も変わってしまいます。）

Comment: 恐らくAudioTrackとMediaCodecなどを組み合わせたサンプルをみつけることができました。
https://github.com/ariestiyansyah/indonesiax-android-app


2倍速で再生したところ、確かに音程が変わって、高い声で再生されました。これを音程を変えてないで再生することは可能なのでしょうか？

Android6以上のMediaPlayerでは可能みたいですが、Android4.1以上で実現する必要があります。

すみませんが、アドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 残念ながら、タイムストレッチについてはOS6.0以上からしか公式のAPIは提供されていません。上のコメント先のリンクにもある通り、サード製のライブラリを利用するか自前で実装するかしかないと思います。

Comment: 過去の質問のところに書いてあった、プレイヤ部品Vitamioを試してみました。音程が変わらず2倍速再生できました。但し、商用利用では有償と書いてありました。よって自前で実装するしか方法がないと思いました。しかし、どのように実装すればよいのかまったくわかりません。NDKなど使ったことがない技術レベルです。具体的な実装方法など参考になるサイトとかありますでしょうか？アドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。