# AndroidのAudioTrackで音程を変えずに2倍速で再生するには

Tags: android

androidでmp3を2倍速で再生しようとしています。

Googleより提供されているExoPlayerに再生速度を指定できる機能を追加したライブラリがあり、試してみたところ、2倍速で再生することができました。
しかし、2倍速にすると音程が高くなります。
ソースを見ると、AudioTrackを使って再生していました。

AudioTrackで音程を変えずに2倍速で再生することは可能なのでしょうか？

アドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

（波形データを加工する方法に関しては、[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/24177/)に回答があります。）

Comment: 重複候補: [androidでmp3を2倍速で再生するには](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/24177/android%e3%81%a7mp3%e3%82%922%e5%80%8d%e9%80%9f%e3%81%a7%e5%86%8d%e7%94%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af)

Comment: 重複候補として挙げられている質問は、手段を特定せずに倍速再生の方法を問うた物です。「AudioTrack」の機能に頼らない方法の回答で解決済みになっています。重複ではありません。